# Symfony2 SyliusRbacBundle Setup

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am exploring the option of using SyliusRbacBundle for my app. I manage to install it along with FosUserBundle. When I got to the setup part I got the following error on running the command 'sylius:rbac:initialize' following the instructions found here: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusRbacBundle/setup.html#setup-roles-and-permissions-in-the-database

```
Initializing Sylius RBAC roles and permissions.
Adding permission "Update product". (app.product_update)
Adding permission "Create product". (app.product_create)
Adding permission "Manage product". (app.product_manage)

  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                
  An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO sylius_role (code, name,  
   description, security_roles, tree_left, tree_right, tree_level, created_at  
  , updated_at, parent_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params  
   ["root", "Root", null, "a:0:{}", null, null, null, "2015-05-11 16:45:34",   
  "2015-05-11 16:45:34", null]:                                                
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tree_left' ca  
  nnot be null

  [PDOException]                                                               
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tree_left' ca  
  nnot be null                                                                 



sylius:rbac:initialize
```

This is how my config.yml looks like:

```
sylius_rbac:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    security_roles:
            ROLE_ADMINISTRATION_ACCESS: Can access backend
    roles:
        app.admin:
            name: Administrator
            description: Administrator
        app.product_manager:
            name: Product Manager
            description: muchos productos
            permissions: [app.product_update, app.product_create]
    roles_hierarchy:
            app.admin: [app.product_manager]
    permissions:
        app.product_update: Update product
        app.product_create: Create product
        app.product_manage: Manage product
    permissions_hierarchy:
            app.product_manage: [app.product_create, app.product_update]
```

Any one has a clue how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: did you install it correctly in like mentioned here ? http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusRbacBundle/installation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Sylius/Rbac` uses the [tree behaviour](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) from the [`Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions`](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions).

You can use this in a Symfony system using the [`stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle`](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst).

Once it has been installed you would need to enable the tree behaviour in your `app/config/config.yml` like..

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            tree: true
```

This should make the listener register correctly and then your fields to be auto-populated.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Qoop, that was the correct answer and it was not on the documentation